# remove strange char and adding a prefix when renaming on ssh

Tags: bash, ssh

i have found this command to replace spaces with underscores:

```
for file in *.jpg; do mv "$file" ${file// /_}; done
```

but many pics have chars like ' @ ñ  and want to remove those automatically and also wanted to add a suffix o prefix.

ex.

```
pic's@nick_0001.jpg
pic's@nick_0003.jpg
pic's@nick_0003.jpg
```

to

```
vacations_pics_nick_0001.jpg
pics_nick_0001_vacations.jpg
```

can you help me?

Comment: Look at the translate `tr` command (e.g. `man tr`)

Comment: NOT clear, please mention 3 simple things always in your post. 1- What is your question with sample Inputs?2- What is your expected output with all your conditions? 3- What have you tried so far? Please add them in your post in CODE TAGS and let us know then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for file in *.jpg
do
 mv "$file" $(sed 's/[^ [:alnum:]]//g;s/ /_/g;s/^/your_prefix/' <<<"$file")
done
```

Should do the job

Answer (score 1):

both solution works fine.

is there a way to use that command on a single line, like the example i give to use with others comand together:

for file in * do mv "$file" "${file//[^a-z0-9]/_}" done;

??'

Comment: Don't post comments as answers, it will get removed. As for the answer, see the example part of my answer to modify either of the solutions as a one-liner (ie. pretty much replace newlines with semicolons but no semicolon after `do`).

Answer (score 0):

Using bash:

```
for file in *
do 
  mv "$file" "${file//[^a-z0-9]/_}"
done
```

Test:

```
$ touch "pic's@nick_0001.jpg"
$ ls
pic's@nick_0001.jpg
$ for file in *; do mv "$file" "${file//[^a-z0-9]/_}"; done
$ ls
pic_s_nick_0001_jpg
```